# ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() returns random bytes?

Tags: java, zip, arrays, java-io

I am trying to write a Junit test for a method I refactored to ensure that the method is still functioning as expected. I noted some odd behavior that I could not figure out.

**Why does Java ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() return some *Random* Bytes?** I think this probably has something to do with memory. Always the 11 byte in the array is *random*. Any insight?

**Here's the method I refactored.**

```
package foo;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipUtil {

    public static byte[] createZip(Map<String, byte[]> files) throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final ZipOutputStream zipfile = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
        String fileName = null;
        ZipEntry zipentry = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : files.entrySet()) {
            fileName = entry.getKey();
            zipentry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            zipfile.putNextEntry(zipentry);
            zipfile.write(files.get(fileName));
        }

        zipfile.close();  
        return bos.toByteArray();  
    }  
}
```

**Test Class**

```
package foo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({})
public class ZipUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void test_createZip() throws Exception {

        // Setup
        Map<String, byte[]> files = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

        byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { 49, 17, 23,
                -29, -126, 111, -72, -112, 48, 32, 91, -28, -14, 112 };

        files.put("foo.txt", byteArr);

        // Test
        byte[] result = ZipUtil.createZip(files);

        // Validations
        byte[] expectedByteArray1 = new byte[] { 80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 46, -120, -11, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7,
                0, 0, 0, 102, 111, 111, 46, 116, 120, 116, 51, 20, 20, 127, -36, -108, -65, 99, -126, -127, 66, -12, -109, 79, 5, 0, 80,
                75, 7, 8, -99, 100, -122, -62, 16, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 80, 75, 1, 2, 20, 0, 20, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 46, -120, -11, 72, -99,
                100, -122, -62, 16, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 102, 111, 111, 46, 116,
                120, 116, 80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 53, 0, 0, 0, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        Assert.assertEquals(144, result.length);

        // a few bytes are "random". So test the first 9 never random bytes
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedByteArray1[i], result[i]);
        }

        // This fails
        // Assert.assertEquals(expectedByteArray1[10], result[10]);

        for (int i = 11; i < 70; i++) {
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedByteArray1[i], result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `zipfile.write(entry.getValue())` would be better than `zipfile.write(files.get(fileName))`.

Comment: Why did you declare `fileName` and `zipEntry` outside of the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test case assumes that successive zip files creating using the same input will result in exactly the same output bytes.  That doesn't appear to be the case - the zip file specification stores the file modification date and time starting at byte 10 (little endian).  This is why the bytes are different starting at that location.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)

That said, I don't think that comparing the bytes in a zip file to a known zip file is a very effective unit test.  A more effective test would be to "round trip" the zip file - extract the compressed files from the newly created archive and compare to the known input files to ensure that they match.

Comment: Nice. Byte 10-11 is the file last modification time. Regarding my unit test, I know it's just 1 unit test that confused me, that's why I asked the question about the ZIP file byte array.